# Make Typescript warn me if i'm using an optional interface field

Tags: typescript

Suppose the following code in Typescript:

```js
interface User {
    name: string,
    surname?: string 
}

const user1: User = { name: "Genarito" }
const user2: User = { name: "Genarito", surname: "Genarote" }

for (const user of [user1, user2]) {
    const surnameInUpper = user.surname.toUpperCase()
}
```

I would like this code to warning me that I'm calling a method on a field that the user may not have, in this case that field is `surname`. Is there a flag to force this kind of check?

Comment: Have you enabled the `strict` compiler option or at least `strictNullChecks`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I've enabled `strictNullChecks` but all I get is the compiler forcing me to add `myType  | null` everywhere as `? ` only indacates that it could be myType or `undefined`, but not `null`, I want something simpler, where every field with `?` has to be checked before being used

Comment: But that's exactly what's happening [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRyIcAthAFzLphSgDmANAcTQK5SkUD81t9EA2QEAvgQIIA9iFrJ2mKAEZqGLAF4cJclWQAiAOIRS9MFL3Jx+abLDzFAJlWLkm7NorVDxuKfNMOLh0vIxMpSAsrAhgpKGQAChs5BSwpGGQAbRTlAOyHAF0AShxWYiS7dE5uCABJEFQABwaNe2gAOkqgijazRuaoAGE4THjCsSA) with `strictNullChecks` - there is an error because `user.surname` might be `undefined`. If that's not what you ask, can you clarify what should be happening?

Comment: You're right! That's exactly what I want. It'd be cool if would be a `strictUndefinedChecks` to not have to fire a lot of warning for other things. If you want make an answer :)

Comment: @Genarito once you are over the pain of first adding strictNullChecks, you'll quickly find it was also worth it for `null`! I would recommend turning on the `strict` flag so you get even better defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I was looking for an option that only checks for `null` values, the closest option, as indicated by user VLAZ, is to set `strictNullChecks` to `true` in `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 2):

replace `surname?: string`  with `surname : string  | undefined`

```
interface User {
      name: string,
      surname : string  | undefined
    }
```

will give you the error (compile-time warning)

> Property 'surname' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type 'User'.ts(2741)